# Has the copy/paste functionality been removed in the RAZR Maxx's Ice Cream Sandwich update?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, copy-paste

Now that I have upgraded my Motorola Rzar Maxx to Ice Cream Sandwich the ability to do a copy and paste from Evernote and Office Suite are no longer available. Instead I have to cut rather than copy, then paste it back in the app and then go to the app you want to past in to paste it. Further there is no longer a menu item to select all text either. Has this functionality been removed by the update?

Comment: Please review the [FAQ]. This site works best for questions that are actual questions for an Android issue that have clear and concrete solutions. Rants disguised as questions are specifically called out as "bad questions".

Answer (score 3):

ICS and Evernote both support "copy" functionality. Highlight the text you want and then press the icon that looks like two overlapping pieces of paper (circled in red):

[image]

If this is missing then you may wan to provide a screenshot of what you see. Although it's possible Motorola removed the "copy" functionality from the system, I would find it somewhat unlikely (and [this forum post](http://www.razrforums.com/forum/droid-razr-ics-help/2191-ics-stock-browser-copy-url.html#post24273) seems to indicate it does exist). Also, the grid icon on the far left (circled in blue) is "select all".

Comment: Also, if you long press any of these icons a toast notification will show it's functionality.